# Flask: How to get all variables passed into a template

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I want to resolve all variables defined on my template html with Flask like this:

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/toto")
def toto():
   toto = [1,2,3]
   tata = [1,2,3]
   titi = [1,2,3]
   return render_template("toto.html", toto=toto, tata=tata, titi=titi)
```

**toto.html**

```
{% set var = ALL_VARIABLE %}
{% for v in var %}
    {{ v }}
{{ endfor }}
```

The `toto.html` file is used for multiple templates and I want to get all variables on template because I add an input who used this variables.

Comment: You can wrap the variables into a dictionary and pass the single dict object into the template, then access as `mydict.toto`.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in your templates like the following:

```
  <ul>
    {% for to in toto %}
    <li>{{to}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <ul>
    {% for to in tata %}
    <li>{{ta}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

or you could concatenate your lists as in:

```
{% set var = tata + toto + titi  %}

  <ul>
    {% for i in var %}
    <li>{{i}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the variables within the for loop

```
<ul>
    {% for t in tata + toto + titi %}
    <li>{{ t }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

A clean method for passing multiple variables into a template is to wrap the variables into a `dict` and pass the single dict object into the template, then access as `mydict.toto`.

For example:

```
{% for v in mydict.toto %}
    {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will not work! Creating a dict like this: `mydict = {"toto":[1,2,3], "tata":[4,5,6], "titi":[7,8,9]}` will only show a list containing the dict keys but not the values. You could however use a nested for loop.

Comment: @agittarius - I have to disagree mate, this works fine because the dict key is accessed explicitly as `mydict.toto`, therefore the iterator prints the contents of the list.  Please give it another look and try.

Comment: That‘s true - but then you only have the values of toto displayed which isn‘t solving the requested problem. Using this dict approach you could use a nester loop to display all values. But in my opinion using a nested loop is not a very nice solution.